# How to limit max length of bindable label?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have label that is bound to my view model. Sometimes the text value of the label is only a few characters, but sometimes it is more than 20 characters.

How to limit maximum length of label text?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the LineBreakMode property:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.label.linebreakmode?view=xamarin-forms

You can set your Label's LineBreakMode to TailTruncation to make the Label truncate any characters that don't fit in its allotted space and replace them with ellipses.

```
<Label Text="{Binding LabelText}" LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" />
```

Then you just need to limit the allotted width of the Label to an acceptable size. How you do that will depend on your specific scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a converter:

```
public class LabelMaxLengthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string labelText = value as string;

        if (labelText == null)
            return value;

        const int maxLength = 20;

        if (labelText.Length > maxLength)
            return labelText.Substring(0, maxLength);
        else
            return labelText;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And in your xaml first define that converter in pages's resouurces:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <converters:LabelMaxLengthConverter x:Key="LabelMaxLengthConverter" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

And finally in your label apply the converter to binding:

```
<Label Text="{Binding LabelText, Converter={StaticResource LabelMaxLengthConverter}}" />
```